# How to write two Handlers using Switch Case

Tags: asp.net

i wrote two handlers but i need to write now only one handler using switch case how to write i tried but not working. please help me. this is my two handlers code i want that in switch case.please solve this problem

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string fname = string.Empty;
    string ffname = string.Empty;
    string m_Result = string.Empty;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

    if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")
            {
                string[] testfiles = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                fname = testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];
            }
            else
            {
                fname = file.FileName;
                ffname = "~/Adds_uploads/" + fname;

            }
            string p = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fname);
            fname = Path.Combine(context.Server.MapPath("~/Adds_uploads/"), p);
            file.SaveAs(fname + id + Path.GetExtension(ffname));
            string dirName1 = new DirectoryInfo(fname).Name;

            FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(ffname);
            String dirName = fInfo.Directory.Name + '/' + dirName1 + id + Path.GetExtension(ffname);

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dirName));
            //RAID = context.Request.QueryString["RA_ID"].ToString();
            //UploadFileToDB(file, RAID);
        }
    }
}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**2nd Handler**

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string fname = string.Empty;
    string ffname = string.Empty;
    string m_Result = string.Empty;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

    if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")
            {
                string[] testfiles = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                fname = testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];
            }
            else
            {
                fname = file.FileName;
                ffname = "~/Fileuploads/" + fname;

            }
            string p = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fname);
            fname = Path.Combine(context.Server.MapPath("~/Fileuploads/"), p);
            file.SaveAs(fname + id + Path.GetExtension(ffname));
            string dirName1 = new DirectoryInfo(fname).Name;

            FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(ffname);
            String dirName = fInfo.Directory.Name + '/' + dirName1 + id + Path.GetExtension(ffname);

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dirName));
            //RAID = context.Request.QueryString["RA_ID"].ToString();
            //UploadFileToDB(file, RAID);
        }
    }
}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only difference if the upload path. I would suggest you to pass along another input form the view and then determine the upload path based on that.

i.e
you would have

```
//for case one
<input type='hidden' name='uploadType' value='files' />
//for case two
<input type='hidden' name='uploadType' value='adds' />
```

inside your individual file upload forms and then on your action method you can just use

```
var mappedDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["uploadType"].ToString() == "adds" ? "~/Adds_uploads/" : "~/Fileuploads/";
```

and use this string in your fname construct. So your new method would be like

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    var mappedDirectory = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["uploadType"].ToString() == "adds" ? "~/Adds_uploads/" : "~/Fileuploads/";
    string fname = string.Empty;
    string ffname = string.Empty;
    string m_Result = string.Empty;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

    if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        HttpFileCollection files = context.Request.Files;
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")
            {
                string[] testfiles = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                fname = testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];
            }
            else
            {
                fname = file.FileName;
                ffname = mappedDirectory + fname;

            }
            string p = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fname);
            fname = Path.Combine(context.Server.MapPath(mappedDirectory), p);
            file.SaveAs(fname + id + Path.GetExtension(ffname));
            string dirName1 = new DirectoryInfo(fname).Name;

            FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(ffname);
            String dirName = fInfo.Directory.Name + '/' + dirName1 + id + Path.GetExtension(ffname);

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dirName));
            //RAID = context.Request.QueryString["RA_ID"].ToString();
            //UploadFileToDB(file, RAID);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where i place that code in my handlers please tell me clearly. i am new to this please

Comment: i think your only changes are on ffname = "~/Fileuploads/" + fname; and fname = Path.Combine(context.Server.MapPath("~/Fileuploads/"), p); So try using the mappedDirectory variable instead of hardcoding the strings, so you end up with one method, you get the idea right

Comment: Yes but still i strucked. with changes.

Comment: will you please tell me more

Comment: updated my answer, try this out, also don't forget to update your views so you get the value from the form as well.

Comment: i am getting this error. Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: in which line, try debugging and find out if the form key in getting passed

Comment: starting line only ( var mappedDirectory)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110601/discussion-between-sadirubaiyet-and-chaitanya).